# WebClient downloads an empty file

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webclient

```
Dim webClient As New WebClient()
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(<<URL>>), <<Workstation Folder>>)
```

Using the above code, it is possible to download a file via its URL. If I download the file from an asp page, which is using Response.BinaryWrite, empty file has been downloaded.

Do anyone know how to solve it?

When using

```
webClient.DownloadFile
```

I catch this error message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download the file from the asp page manually from a web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox...)? This way you could check if the error is in the client side or in the server side.

Perhaps in the asp page code you has forgotten to use Response.End after the Response.BinaryWrite?

Hope this hint helps you!